# Angular 4: best option for data sharing service with large objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to decide what approach to use (Observables, BehaviorSubject, Redux, etc.) in order to create a service for data sharing between unrelated components.

I have a Data Service which contains one big array of items (over 10k), which will be fetched over HTTP and updated locally.

This items will be shown in different components, and its attributes can be updated in any of this components. After any update, all components must reflect the changes made to an item.

Which will be the best option to achieve this in terms of performance?

I'm thinking of using a BehaviorSubject and calling "next" on every update of an item, but I'm not sure if this might be the best option.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I voted to close this because it is primarily an opinion based question.

Comment: By the way, I already used your behaviourSubject approach, and it worked fine to share data/ handle cache between components. There is no need to be highly coupled to redux.

Comment: I agree with @DeblatonJean-Philippe. I worked with all of these scenarios and I think that this is opinion based. Basically, any of the answers here can be downvoted and upvoted at the same time.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you. I agree with you this is opinion based, but I find it useful to read about your experiences. Even if you can up/downvote multiple answers, I don't see why that could be harmful. I see it as a way of having an idea of what more experienced people thinks about going for different approaches for the same problem. Others can read them and vote for their preferred(s) choice(s).

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe in your implementation, could you tell how the components received the small set of data it needed from the service? 
I am facing a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428876/angular-service-that-returns-observables-subjects-from-a-cache-array-to-multiple/56431444

Answer (score 2):

if I was you, I would use the following architecture.

- Create a class that you will use as an in memory data storage. Something simple. (the main array placeholder)
- Create then a service that would fetch, update and set the in memory storage class. (ex. getById, updateById)
- And then you create the services that deliver the correct model where you need it.

In your component, you subscribe to observables inside your model services, who at their turn, will subscribe to subjects inside your 'in memory storage' service. Those subjects are like you stated, are 'Subject and calling "next" '

**Example**
I used the same architecture for my auth module

```
export class AuthService {

  // is authenticated flag subject
  isAuthenticatedSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  login(username: string, password: string): void {

    this.documentumService.login( username, password )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // store user details in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem( this.tokenLabel , JSON.stringify({ token: this.documentumService.getAuthToken() }));

          // edit isAuthSubject
          this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);

          // store response json
          this.authResponse = data;
        },
        err  => {
          this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
        },
        null
      );

  }

export class LoginComponent {

  login(): void {

    this.loading = true;

    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password);

    this.authenticationService.isAuthenticatedSubject
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data) {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          } else { this.loading = false; }
        },
        error => {
          // this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
```

Comment: If I understand this answer well, you create stateful services, that you need to initialize before being able to consume the data?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe yes, preferably on startup of the app. You fetch once, and you update it locally (like OP asked) or you could even send your updates back to the http endpoint for persistence

Comment: Thank you @VikingCode. Actually after my initial research I also found this the best way to achieve it. As it is pretty straightforward to see it for working with "small data" like numbers, strings, etc.; it was not so for large arrays with frequent updates. My main concern is about Angular performance updating big data tables after each change.

Answer (score -2):

I think, in your scenario, using ng2-redux will be the best option. It has been built with the sole purpose of maintaining states in a large application with unrelated components, such as yours.

I mean, it will maintain the state of your data, and update/add/delete it across all components at a time. To see how to use it, I suggest you subscribe to the Udemy course on this.

It is the best at the moment.

Comment: redux is dedicated to store states . Not big arrays, it will be inefficient.