# Angular service that returns observables/subjects from a cache array to multiple instances of a component in realtime

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, observable, angular7

**USE CASE**

[image: BlogComponents with Multiple <code>UserActionsComponent</code>s each]

I have a content page that has multiple instances of UserActionsComponent. I also have a global DataService that acts as a data provider with (wannabe) advanced caching.

Data fetch hierarchy:

*In-Memory Cache >> Browser Storage (async) >> HTTP Request*

**UserActionsComponent**

Requests `dataService.getData(URL,params,method)`

PS: `params` has details like blogId which makes the hash signature unique

**DataService (.getData())**

1) Makes a unique hash KEY using something like genUniqueHash(URL+stringify(params)+method)

2) Checks if value is present in an in-memory cache (array[KEY]) - If yes, return ob$

3) Check if value is present in browser's storage (async; uses Ionic storage) - If yes, return ob$ else - save to in-memory cache, then return ob$(array[KEY])

4) Get the value from HTTP Call, save to Storage, save to in-memory cache and return ob$(array[KEY])

This concept is not working as I am not able to figure out how to return a shared observable (I'm guessing this should be a BehaviourSubject?) from an array of cache values. Please bring me on the right track.

**NOTES**

- If user votes up in one component, it must reflect on all the others instances in view (all of that particular Blog Entry's UserActionsComponent should update)
- There can be many UserActionsComponent in one view (Eg: For BlogEntry#1 and BlogEntry#25) on the same page!
- The In-memory cache keeps growing as the user visits new Blog Posts (that's fine as it's a finite set)

I'm a noob to RxJS. I tried my luck with:

- pipe(share()) [Since it's a service, the pipe was shared with all URLs]
- returning of(cache[key]) [Didn't work as the last fetched BlogEntry's User Actions would reflect on all subscriptions]
- returning the whole cache and then filtering out required data (using array[KEY]) at UserActionsComponent end **(This is the current implementation)**

The current implementation works, but it doesn't seem the best way to do it for this use case. Reason being: One view might have up-to 20 UACs [UAC-A(1), UAC-B(1), UAC(200) ...]. UAC emits next() twice. onInit of UAC and when user up-votes or down-votes in a UAC. Now since on change, we emit the cache data, an array of size 20 is emitted 2*20 times for this page view.

What would be the most optimized way to implement this using RxJS?

Comment: You want to return an observable when you find the data in any of the caches so that all the instances of UserActionController can subscribe to it and update their value. This is the task?

Comment: Yes, that's right. UserActionComponent receives @Input() of blog post id; There are multiple instances of UserActionController for blogPost#1 and blogPost#3 (say) on the same page. DataService has a array used as cache

Comment: Have you considered using subject?

Comment: I did, but this is the first time I'd be using it. I'm unsure how to create multiple BehaviourSubjects from the DataService (as there could be multiple blogPosts, each with multiple UserActionsComps [UAC]). When I tried, the BehaviourSubject was all showing the same value for BlogPost#1's UACs and BlogPost#2's UAC. What is the right way to create multiple Subjects from the service ?

Comment: use `Map` instead of `Array` and later get needed item from cache by `key`

Comment: So I filter by `key` on cache Map at the DataService end? Current implementation filters by `key` at the UAC end. Any change in cache is emitted to all UACs using next(). How can I make sure cache(1) goes to all instances of UAC(1), cache(x) goes to UAC(X) and so on ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only one Subject/Behaviour Subject. Return that as an observable which every UAC can subscribe to and listen for data. Now I am assuming there must be some unique identifier attached to every UAC, let's say a blog Id. So when you emit a data using Subject, along with data, append that blog Id as well in that data. In the UAC match if the UAC's id is the same as the id received from observable then update the data in UAC else ignore. This way the right UAC will be updated.
For example:-

*data.service.ts*

```
const a = new BehaviourSubject();

getDataSource() {
 return a.asObservable():
}

cacheCheck(blogId: string) {
  // emit the data with a blogId.
  a.next({'id': blogId, 'data': getDataFromSomeWhere()})
}
```

*blog.component.html*

```
<app-uac [id]="blogId"></app-uac>
```

*uac.component.ts*

```
@Input id: string;
constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}
ngOnInit() {
   dataService.getDataSource().subscribe((data) => {
      if(data.id == this.id) //do somethin in UAC or emit event to parent
         //blog and let it do something
      else { //ignore}
   })
}
```

Something on this line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is similar to the current implementation I have (returns whole cache and UAC filters what it needs) but not using Subject.

Comment: So, when the user up votes via a particular blog post's UAC, I update data.service and emit a next() on that case too, right ?

Comment: In what conditions are you fetching the data from the cache or http requests?
Whenever user clicks on UAC?

Comment: Can you brief about the flow on what action you fetch the data and where does it update the screen?

Comment: Whenever the BlogPost#1 is loaded, it calls UAC with BlogId:1. 
UAC then checks for cache in this order: In-Memory Cache >> Browser Storage (async) >> HTTP Request
UAC loads data on 1) onInit and then refreshes on 2)User does some action on that component

Comment: If you can manage to get the id in the data you received, you know which UAC it's meant for, then you can update only those UAC and blog page that holds it by emitting to it. Is there any other issue you are facing? I may still have confusion understanding your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am wondering if there is a better approach than emitting out an array with 100 objects to a UAC that will use  1 row from it. And there could be upto 20 UACs on a page. Each UAC receives minimum of 2 emits.  That's 40 Emits of array of 100 objects each!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194405/discussion-between-emkay-and-deepak-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

Current Implementation:

Writing it down as it would be helpful for someone in the future. 
I managed to optimize it using observable pattern this way:

- UAC onInit() calls `dataService.getData(url,params,method,guid)`
- The `guid` passed by the UAC is the cache key for the service
- UAC has two subscriptions from dataService. One is dataService.getData method that returns an observable - mainly used as an initializer to set `guid` - it unsubscribes after getting its first value using `.pipe(first())`. Second subscription is to a BehaviourSubject called dataChanged. Whenever data is changed on dataService cache, it emits `dataChanged.next(newDataDelta)`. This subscription persists till the component's onDestroy.
- dataService checks hierarchically as `cache[guid] > storage[guid] > http[url]`, sets data accordingly, and finally calls `dataChangedSubj.next(cache[guid])` *Only the changed delta would be emitted*
- All UACs receive the new cached DataSet (which is cache[guid]; contains only what was changed) and checks for `receivedData[guid]` to see if the emitted data is relevant to the UAC. If yes, it consumes it.
- If user up-votes/down-votes on a UAC, UAC does necessary API calls, and on success, does dataService.updateData(guid,data), which in-turn emits the change using `dataChanged.next(newDataDelta)` to all UACs and the UACs that belong to the same blog post would update its data (as they would have the same guid)

Still open for the best way to implement this use case using RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

what about the following solution:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {map, shareReplay} from "rxjs/operators";
import {HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyCache {
  private _data$: Observable<MyEntity[]> | undefined;

  public get(): Observable<MyEntity[]> {
    if (!this._data$) {
      this._data$ = myQuery()
        .pipe(map((res: HttpResponse<MyEntity[]>) => res.body ?? []))
        .pipe(shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }))
    }
    return this._data$;
  }
}
```